# Send cell data from one Google sheet to another and then overwrite data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a Google sheet (Employee Timesheet) that documents employees' hours each day for the week. Once that week has finished (Monday - Friday) the data gets the overwritten with next weeks data. I need the data to be sent to another Google Sheet (Employee Data) where it will be stored. How can I send that data for it then to be documented and not removed once overwritten the following week?

Comment: An alternative to the excellent suggestion by @player0 might be `sheet.copyTo(destination);` [Doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) "Copies the sheet to a given spreadsheet, which can be the same spreadsheet as the source. The copied sheet is named "Copy of [original name]". There are pros and cons to both approaches, mostly depending on how (if at all), you wish to use the data after the event.

Answer (score 0):

you will need something like this:

```
function tc() {
    var reference = 'sheet1!A2'; 
    var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
    rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A5:H");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var values = source.getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})});
destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

anytime cell `sheet1!A2` changes the range `Sheet1!A5:H` gets archived in `Sheet2`